# Class layout: Do all objects created from the same most derived polymorphic class type share a unique memory layout?

Tags: c++, memory-layout

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Layout:

> **Layout**:
>   When an object of some class C is created, each non-static data member of non-reference type is allocated in some part of the object representation of C.

Q1: Is it also true for object of (possibly virtual) base class and non-static data member of (possibly virtual) base class?

Q2: If the answer of Q1 is true, is that layout identical
 from each object of **the most derived class**? For example, do all objects created from class C share a unique layout (eg. data member offsets and vtable for virtual bases), even among multiple compilation units?

Q3: If the answer of Q2 is true, is it safe to access data members by adding offset to address of object of the most derived class ? (I guess it is, becase casting a non-function pointer to char* then casting back would be safe.)

For more detail and more generally, is the following piece of code guaranteed running safely?
(Note: As this code is a bit long, you don't have to read it unless you need more detail about Qs. You can also leave a comment and let me edit better.)

Thanks.

```cpp
// test_layout.cpp

#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
char* cast(T* p) {
  return reinterpret_cast<char*>(p);
}

void on_constructing_X(char*);

class X {
public:
  X() {
    x_ = ++counter_;
    // do init
    on_constructing_X(cast(this));
  }

  void do_something() {
    // bala bala
    std::cout << "X@" << this << " " << x_ << std::endl;
  }

private:
  int x_;
  // bala bala

  static int counter_;
};
int X::counter_ = 0;

struct Info {
  char* begin;
  char* end;
  std::vector<long>* offsets;
  bool init;
};

static std::vector<Info> constructing_wrapper;

template<typename T>
class Wrapper {
private:
  union {
    T data_;
    char dummy_;
  };
  static bool init_;
  static std::vector<long> offsets_;

private:
  template<typename...Args>
  Wrapper(Args&&...args): dummy_(0) {
    std::cout << "constructing Wrapper at " << this << std::endl;
    constructing_wrapper.push_back({cast(this), cast(this) + sizeof(*this), &offsets_, init_});
    new (&data_) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    constructing_wrapper.pop_back();
    init_ = true;
  }

public:
  ~Wrapper() {
    data_.~T();
  }

  template<typename...Args>
  static Wrapper* Make(Args&&...args) {
    return new Wrapper(std::forward<Args>(*args)...);
  }

  template<typename F>
  void traversal_X(F&& f) {
    for (auto off: offsets_) {
      f(reinterpret_cast<X*>(cast(this) + off));
    }
  }

};

template<typename T>
bool Wrapper<T>::init_ = false;

template<typename T>
std::vector<long> Wrapper<T>::offsets_;

void on_constructing_X(char* x) {
  if (!constructing_wrapper.empty()) {
    auto i = constructing_wrapper.back();
    if (i.begin <= x && x + sizeof(X) <= i.end) {
      if (!i.init) {
        i.offsets->push_back(x - i.begin);
      } else {
        bool found = false;
        for (auto off: *i.offsets) {
          if (x - i.begin == off) {
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!found) {
          std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
          std::abort();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

namespace test {
  class B { X xb; };
  class D1: B { X xd1; };
  class D2: protected virtual B { X xd2; };
  class D3: protected virtual B { X xd3; };
  class DD: D1, D2, D3 { X xdd; };

  void test() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      auto p = Wrapper<D2>::Make();
      p->traversal_X([](X* x) {x->do_something();});
      delete p;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      auto p = Wrapper<DD>::Make();
      p->traversal_X([](X* x) {x->do_something();});
      delete p;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  test::test();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. This is the reason you need complete definitions of a class and all base classes as soon as you create objects of it.-- Casting to a void pointer and back is guaranteed to work; to a char pointer I'm not sure.

Comment: Why would you think that different instantiations of a type would have different memory layout?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't think it's likely to occur, but I can't see anything in the standard that forbids it from happening.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I can't find anything saying about this. And for polymorphic types, I think it might be possible using different layout for virtual bases, as long as there are multiple vtable for that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the object representation contains all the data stored in the object, including all non-static data members and base classes, whether virtual or not. The definition of *object representation* in C++17 is:

> the sequence of *N* `unsigned char` objects taken up by the object of type `T`, where *N* equals `sizeof(T)`.

Clearly, any bytes that are used to store subobjects are "taken up" by the object, since the subobject is part of the object. That means those bytes are part of the object representation. This should hopefully answer your Q1.

For Q2, I don't think that the standard guarantees that all complete objects of the same type will have the same layout, unless the type is standard-layout. In practice I think it would be unusual to find an implementation where complete objects of the same type could have different layouts. If every translation unit sees the same definition of the class (which it should, otherwise you are violating then ODR) then the compiler should have no problem with generating the same layout in each translation unit, and this just seems like the sensible thing to do (otherwise you may have to generate multiple vtables). But, if for some reason an implementation did want to vary the layout, I think that it could do so, even within a single translation unit.

But in addition I would question whether pointer arithmetic would be allowed, even if the layout were guaranteed! If `T` is neither a standard-layout nor trivially copyable type, then it's not clear to me whether you're even allowed to do pointer arithmetic within an object of type `T`, using a `char*` that points to one of the bytes of `T`. Consider for example that `offsetof` is only guaranteed to be supported for standard-layout types, and `memcpy`ing an object into a byte array and back is only guaranteed to be well-defined for trivially copyable types. Let's say a type has a virtual base class, making it neither standard-layout nor trivially copyable. I am not sure whether this code is well-defined:

```
struct B {};
struct D : virtual B {};
auto foo() {
    D d;
    B* pb = &d;
    return reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb) - reinterpret_cast<char*>(&d);
}
```

If it's not even well-defined to call `foo` at all, then the question of whether it always returns the same value is obviously moot. Perhaps offsets within these types are just not observable (according to the rules of the abstract machine).

Comment: How on earth do you imagine a function in one TU which gets an object, ref or pointer  of/to a type T *do* anything with that object if this TU has a different conception of T's memory layout!? Of course it has the same layout in every TU. That's the reason for the ODR and the reason you need the complete class definition (and the definition of all subobjects and members, recursively) when you create an object of T (by copy or by initialization).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Well, in the case of virtual base classes, in order to access the subobject, the compiler has to look at the vtable to see what the offset is. So, it's not entirely impossible that, even for two objects of the same complete type, the virtual base classes could be located at different offsets. They would just have to have different vtables.

Comment: The function in TU A creates an object. The object is a blob of bytes, where bytes n..n+x etc. have specific meaning, including base classes, virtual or not. This object is passed to a function in TU B *by value*. TU B cannot have a different class layout in mind than TU A and interpret bytes n..n+x differently.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica if the type is not trivially copyable, then the act of copying it is allowed to change the vptr or even create an entirely new vtable, so the compiler could very well decide to change the offset of the virtual base.

Comment: OK, so I convinced you for trivially copyable types? ;-)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes. I think that a trivially copyable type must always have the same layout, after all, the standard does guarantee that `memcpy` works.

Comment: Then let's pass a *pointer* to T from TU A to TU B, and TU B has a different idea of the layout (no copying involved!). Does not sound good, does it? Have I convinced you now? ;-) (Imagine somebody doing a cast to virtual base in TU B, or from virtual base ptr to derived...)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think you misunderstood me. I am not saying that two different TUs can have in mind different *fixed* offsets for a virtual base class. I am saying that, perhaps, every time an object gets created, the compiler determines the virtual base class offset randomly, and then stores that information inside the object itself. So any TU that gets a hold of that object can find the virtual base class, but only by looking up the offset for that specific object.

Comment: OK, so I convinced you also of non-trivially copyable classes, butnot yet of polymorphic ones.

Comment: For pointer arithmetic, I found this on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/cast#Explanation): `If a pointer to object is cast to pointer to any character type, the result points at the lowest byte of the object and may be incremented up to sizeof the target type (in other words, can be used to examine object representation or to make a copy via memcpy or memmove).` It seems to allow pointer arithmetic within an object?

Comment: @VainMan That's from the "C" section of the site.

Comment: @Brian oh, sorry for mistake. .What if we cast pointer to integer, do arithmetic on interger and cast the result to pointer? In other words, is it guaranteed `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p) + offset == reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p + offset)` for p is `char*` ？

Comment: @VainMan There's no guarantee that `reinterpret_cast` gives the actual numerical address.